# Regarding java based Spring Configuration: How to use bean generated in one of my dependency in my project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo

I have a doubt in using beans generated by another project. To be more detail :

I have a project A as follows

```
public A {
public void print()
{
System.out.println("Hello World");
}
}
```

The config class is as follows

```
@Configuration
public class AConfig {  
@Bean
public A a()
{
    A bean = new A();
    return A;
}
}
```

Now I have a new project B  which has class as follows

```
public B {
A a;
public setA()
{
this.a = a;
}
public static void main(String[] args)  
{ 
System.out.println(a.print());
}
}
```

config class for B as follows

```
@Configuration
@Import(AConfig.class)
public BConfig
{
@Bean
public B b()
{
B bean = new B();
**b.setA(a());-----------------This is not correct. How can i get Instance of class A NOw????**
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Merge `@Configuration` classes

If beans are tightly coupled, just put them in the same class:

```
@Configuration
public class AConfig {  
    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setA(a());
        return b;
    }
}
```

## Inject another `@Configuration` class

`@Configuration` class is just a special case of a bean in Spring:

```
@Configuration
public class BConfig {  

    @Autowired
    private AConfig aConfig;

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setA(aConfig.a());
        return b;
    }
}
```

## Inject dependencies to `@Configuration` class

```
@Configuration
@Import(AConfig.class)
public class BConfig {  

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setA(a);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for multiple answers